# CSS to change one element flex-direction

Tags: css

I have a form where all of the elements use the CSS flex property to handle mobile devices.  The flex direction is "row" by default, but I have one element on the page that needs to be forced to "column".

I can manually change, the flex-direction in FF developer tools and it works fine (see image below).  However, when I try to modify my CSS file to make the same change, it doesn't take effect.

[image]

I tried the CSS below, but it didn't work.

`#field_2_14 #content .page .gform_wrapper ul li {
    flex-direction:column;
}`

What am I doing wrong with my CSS file?

Comment: How is the id `#field_2_14` generated?  Did you write that id name or is it being auto-generated by something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex-direction` requires `display:flex`.

> Note that you can see a hint by pressing the `i` icon in the inspector